# Use of type : object and properties in JSON schema

Tags: jsonschema

I'm new to JSON.

I see in various examples of JSON, like the following, where complex values are prefixed with `"type":"object", properties { }`

```
{
 "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
 "motor" : { 
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "class" : "string",
    "voltage" : "number",
    "amperage" : "number"
  }
 }
}
```

I have written JSON without type, object, and properties, like the following.

```
{
 "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
 "motor" : { 
    "class" : "string",
    "voltage" : "number",
    "amperage" : "number"
 }
}
```

and submitted to an on-line JSON schema validator with no errors.

What is the purpose of `type:object, properties { }`? Is it optional?

Comment: I'm not sure what answer you were really looking for so I took an attempt an answered it.  If you really just want to understand object and properties then read https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html

Comment: Hi Keith. Can you give a bit of context on this? Where have you seen this sort of schema? It's... unusual, and you certinly wouldn't write it like that.

Comment: Also, it would help frame my answer if you can share what you believe `type:object, properties { }` does on its own. I'm not toally clear what you're asking... can you be more specific please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is optional, try removing it and use your validator.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

You actually don't even need to use the [$schema keyword](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/schema.html) i.e. `{}` is valid json

I would start by understanding what json is, https://www.json.org/ is the best place to start but you may prefer something easier to read like  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp.

A schema is just a template (or definition) to make sure you're producing valid json for the consumer

As an example let's say you have an application that parses some json and looks for a key named `test_score` and saves the value (the score) in a database in some table/column.  For this example we'll call the table `tests` and the column `score`.  Since a database column requires a [type](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/sql/sql_datatypes_general.asp.html) we'll choose a numeric type, i.e. `integer` for our `score` column.

A valid json example for this may look like

```
{
 "test_score": 100
}
```

Following this example the application would parse the key `test_score` and save the value `100` to the `tests.score` database table/column.

But let's say a score is absent so you put in a string i.e `"NA"`

```
{
 "test_score": "NA"
}
```

When the application attempts to save `NA` to the database it will error because `NA` is a string not an integer which the database expects.

If you put each of those examples into any online json validator they are valid json example.  However, while it's valid json to use `"NA"` or `100` it is not valid for the actual application that needs to consume the json.

So now you may understand that the author of the json may wonder

> What are the different valid types I can use as values for my test
>   score?

The responsibility then falls on the writers of the application to provide some sort of definition (i.e a schema) that the clients (authors) can reference so the author knows exactly how to structure the json so the application can process it accordingly.  Having a schema also allows you to validate/test your json so you know it can be processed by the application without actually having to send your json through the application.

So putting it altogether let's say in the schema you see

```
"$test_score": {
    "type": "integer",
    "format": "tinyint"
},
```

The writer of the json now knows that they must pass an integer and the range is `0 to 255` because it's a tinyint.  They no longer have to trial by error different values and see which ones the application process.  This is a big benefit to having a schema.

Comment: Yes I understand the purpose of a schema. What I don't understand is the purpose of the type/object/properties construct. JSON seems complete without it. It adds a lot extra text for what seems to be no value. As you said, it is optional.